# break flexbox and start in next column of same row

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to make a css layout where after a certain element suppose `:nth-child(6)` the elements should break and form a separate column in the same row. The parent element should break into 2 columns after every 6th element in the same row and once all 12 are complete it should go to the next row and form the same above rule. This is possible using divs but I need to make it dynamic so should be using flexblox and grid in achieving so.

HTML:

```
  <div class="home__content">
    <!-- sub cards -->
    <div class="sub__card">
      <div class="home__subcardContainer">
        <h4>একটা যুগের অবসান, চলে গেলেন সকলের প্রিয় ফেলুদা সকলের প্রিয় ফেলুদা</h4>
      </div>
      <img class="subcard__image"
        src="https://sambadkolkata.in/uploads/post_main_image/1605424509_image_IMG-20201114-WA0230.jpg" alt="Avatar"
        style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub__card">
      <div class="home__subcardContainer">
        <h4>একটা যুগের অবসান, চলে গেলেন সকলের প্রিয় ফেলুদা সকলের প্রিয় ফেলুদা</h4>
      </div>
      <img class="subcard__image"
        src="https://sambadkolkata.in/uploads/post_main_image/1605424509_image_IMG-20201114-WA0230.jpg" alt="Avatar"
        style="width:100%">
    </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sub__card {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2%;
}

.sub__card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.home__subcardContainer {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.subcard__image {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.home__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5% 0%;
}

.home__contentLeft {
  flex: 0.5;
}

.home__contentRight {
  flex: 0.5;
}

.sub__card:nth-child(1) {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.sub__card:nth-child(1) > .subcard__image {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.sub__card:nth-child(7) {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.sub__card:nth-child(7) > .subcard__image {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.sub__card:nth-child(6) {
  break-after: always;
}
```

[image]

Comment: try using `grids`, here is a [quick guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved easily with css grid.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 6em);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.item {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  height: 4em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/dasshounak/pen/xxOvXYz) link. You can edit the code and see it in action.